# Finding the size of a file from stdin gives incorrect number

Tags: c, linux, file, stat

I am reading a file name off the standard input and the function returns something that is completely wrong. The code below returns 4294967296 rather than what should be 7. I am running the file like this on linux:

echo "p3test.txt" | ./totalsize

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <errno.h>

//find the file size
off_t filesize(const char* fileName){
    printf("%s", fileName);

    struct stat st;
    if(stat(fileName, &st) == 0)
        printf("%zd", st.st_size);
        return st.st_size;


    fprintf(stderr, "Cannot determine size of %s: %s\n",
        fileName, strerror(errno));

    return -1;

}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char tmpstring[1024];
    const char* fileName;
    off_t size;

    while (fgets(tmpstring, 1024, stdin)) 
  {
    fileName = tmpstring;
    size = filesize(fileName);
  }
}
```

Comment: You are probably missing some curly braces.

Comment: I cant see where that would be, it compiles correctly and my bracket highlighters say my brackets are fine

Comment: @FullCombatBeard two idented lines after `if(stat(fileName, &st) == 0)` without braces look strange.

Comment: The code after the first `return` statement in `filesize` will never be executed.

Comment: If _R Sahu's_ answer helped, you could up click his answer, and/or click the hollow check mark just under the up click arrows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use:

```
while (fgets(tmpstring, 1024, stdin))
```

you get the `'\n'` in `tmpstring`. Trim that character from the name before calling `filesize`.

Also, the lines

```
if(stat(fileName, &st) == 0)
    printf("%zd", st.st_size);
    return st.st_size;
```

should be:

```
if(stat(fileName, &st) == 0)
{
    printf("%zd", st.st_size);
    return st.st_size;
}
```

Otherwise, the `if` statement terminates at the `printf` line and you end up returning `st.st_size` regardless of the return value of `stat`.

**Update**

Thanks to @chux for the suggestion. The format `"%zd"` might not be appropriate for the type used for `stat.st_size`. You should use:

```
    printf("%jd", (intmax_t)st.st_size);
```

Comment: This is it, I did not know fgets returns a new line, thank you!

Comment: Not certain that `"z"` is a fully portable specifier as `"z"` is for `size_t` and `st.st_size` is some signed type called `off_t`.  Suggest `printf("%lld", (long long) st.st_size);` or `printf("%jd", (intmax_t) st.st_size);`.